# if $f_n \to f$ and $f_n$ are measurable, then show $f$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

the solution writes, $\{ x: f(x) > c \} = \cup_n \{x: f_n(x) > c\}$, then concludes. But surely this isn't true, as if $f(x) > c$ this means that there is a number $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have the required inequality. Would that not translate as $\{ x: f(x) > c \} = \cup_{N=1}^\infty\cap_{n\geq N} \{x: f_n(x) > c \}?$

Comment: Perhaps in your case the sequence $(f_n)$ is assumed to be *increasing*?

Comment: yes sorry, they are

Comment: So what is your question now?

Comment: Even if the $(f_n)$ are increasing, I don't see why the solutions hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $f_{n} \leq f_{n+1}$ which imples $f_n<f$. Suppose $f(x)>c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. We just need to show that there exists $n_0$ such that $f_{n_0}(x) > c$. Observe that we have;

$$f_{n_0}  = (f_{n_0}- f) + f> (f_{n_0} - f) + c$$

By the convergence of $f_n \to f$, given any $\epsilon > 0, \exists k$ such that $|f_k-f|<\epsilon \Rightarrow -\epsilon< f_k - f< \epsilon$. Choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ then $f_k > (f_k - f) + c> c - \frac{1}{n}$. The left hand side is independent of $n$ so we can take $n \to  \infty$ and get $f_k \geq c$. (*) We can assume that there exists $n>k$ such that $f_k < f_{n} \leq f_{n+1}$ and so;

$$\{x:f(x)>c\} = \bigcup_{n>k} \{x: f_n(x)>c\}$$

Notice that is there exists a $z$ such that $f_j(z)>c$ where $j \leq k$ then $f_n(z)>c$ for $n \geq j$ by the increasing property of our sequence i.e;

$$\{x:f(x)>c\} = \bigcup_{n>k} \{x: f_n(x)>c\} = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \{x: f_n(x)>c\}$$

The above assumption (*) comes from the fact that if there exists no such $n$ then $f_n = f_k$ for all $n \geq k$ (by increasing property) i.e $f_k = f$ and so we have;

$$\{x:f(x)>c\} = \{x: f_k(x)>c\} = \bigcup_{n \geq k} \{x:f_n(x)>c\} = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \{x: f_n(x)>c\}$$

Comment: thanks for the answer - could you perhaps explain why my answer is incorrect? and would my result hold even if the $f_n$ are not increasing?

Comment: I will need to think about my answer again, but do you see that it does follow quickly if then $f_n$ are decreasing?

Comment: no, I don't see it immediately

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, note that $f= \limsup_n f_n$ (and $\liminf_n f_n)$. We can write $$\limsup_n f_n=\inf_n \sup_{k\geq n} f_k.$$ Now you just have to prove that the sup and inf of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable.

For this, if $s=\sup_n s_n$, then we actually do have $$\{x :s(x)>c\}=\bigcup_n \{x: s_n(x)>c\},$$ and similarly for inf.